# Question about the verb 「いただき」

Tags: grammar, verbs

Here is the sentence from an instruction manual of hair iron.

> ここに示した注意事項は、製品を安全に正しく**お使いいただき**、あなたや他の人々への危害や損害を未然に防止するためのものです。

My translation is below.

> For the warning indicated in this part, use the product according to the instruction safely in order to prevent danger and damage that might happen to you and other people.

I would like to know that if the pattern 'Continuative stem form verb + いただき' hold the same meaning of the patter 'て form verb + いただく' as 'Do something for someone'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both 使っていただく and お使いいただく are honorific expressions, and are usually interchangeable. The latter sounds politer and more respectful, but the former pattern is polite enough in most business settings. Saying 製品を安全に正しく使っていただき is equally fine.

Some dedicated honorific expressions are available only in the latter form; for example, you can say お求めいただく, which is an honorific version of 買う, but 求めていただく sounds funny.